# Is there a current walkthrough on Web Deploy Installation and Configuration?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, msdeploy, webdeploy

I've tried on a couple of different servers to install Web Deploy and it works to the extent that I need it to, but I haven't identified what the missing steps are.

Where it falls down is after installing what appears to be the requisites here:
http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy

There is only occasionally the option for "Configure for Web Deploy Publishing" in the context menu on the site. Does anyone have a guide for this for proper deployment?  How to enable the option?

Deployment in these cases is *not* through WebPI. I have to download packages separately and install manually.  Can't find something that details this with current links, screen shots or advice.

Base Windows Server 2008 server with nothing special installed.  Happy to clarify anything if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Could you clarify the issue? You've installed MSDeploy v3 but "Deploy" doesn't appear in the context menu for a site?

Comment: Thanks Richard, on different servers I was getting positive results to be able to export the profile, others I was not.  Deploy was always there, but the sub menu only contained export/import site, but not "Configure for Web Deploy Publishing".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix (provided by Kristina Olson of Microsoft) was to uninstall Web Deploy and then make sure all the pre-requisites are in place.  There is mention of this in this article:

http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy

Key points:

- Make sure Web Management Service handler component in IIS is installed and enabled
- Make sure PowerShell v2 is installed
- Database dependencies need to be installed
- Make sure to select the complete install